# How to understand that field is Number?

Tags: java, reflection, casting, numbers, primitive-types

I have the method which accepts `Field` and `Object`

```
public String format(Field field, Object o) {....}
```

I want to know if field can be cast to number.

I have noticed that if write something like this(for long primitive):

```
field.getType().isAssignableFrom(long.class)
```

returns `true`

**but**

```
field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Long.class)
```

returns `false`

and

```
field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Number.class)
```

returns `false` too

---

Also

```
field.getType().cast(Number.class)
```

returns `ClassCastException`

Please help to write method which will return `true` if field is actually number(`int`, `long`, `byte`...,also all wrappers) and `false` in other cases.

Is there simpler way than :

```
public String format(Field field, Object o) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object value = null;
    try {
        value = field.get(o);
        if (value instanceof Number) {
            return field.get(o).toString();
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        ....
    }
   ...
}
```

?

Comment: try if(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())). And read the java docs for more details for this method.

Comment: @zombie this answer already exists and it wrong

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between what isAssignableFrom(type) gives you and what reflection gives you: isAssignableFrom checks for direct type assignment compatibility, while reflection implicitly performs boxing/unboxing for primitives. You have to account for that difference explicitly. One way to do this is to represent the compatible primitives in a Set and accept any type that the set includes as well as Number assignment compatible types:

```
private final static Set<Class<?>> NUMBER_REFLECTED_PRIMITIVES;
static {
    Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<>();
    s.add(byte.class);
    s.add(short.class);
    s.add(int.class);
    s.add(long.class);
    s.add(float.class);
    s.add(double.class);
    NUMBER_REFLECTED_PRIMITIVES = s;
}

public static boolean isReflectedAsNumber(Class<?> type) {
    return Number.class.isAssignableFrom(type) || NUMBER_REFLECTED_PRIMITIVES.contains(type);
}
```

Be wary though that you may encounter unexpected types fulfilling the condition, e.g. BigDecimal, AtomicLong etc. *are* subtypes of Number.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for something like:

```
private static final Set<Class<?>> primitiveNumbers = Stream
        .of(int.class, long.class, float.class, 
            double.class, byte.class, short.class)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

private static boolean isNumericType(Class<?> cls) {
    if (cls.isPrimitive()) {
        return primitiveNumbers.contains(cls);
    } else {
        return Number.class.isAssignableFrom(cls);
    }
}
```

You can add another utility method to handle `Filed` like:

```
private static boolean holdsNumericType(Field f) {
    return isNumericType(f.getType());
}
```

Demo:

```
System.out.println(isNumericType(int.class));       //true
System.out.println(isNumericType(Integer.class));   //true
System.out.println(isNumericType(byte.class));      //true
System.out.println(isNumericType(Byte.class));      //true
System.out.println(isNumericType(Character.class)); //false
System.out.println(isNumericType(Boolean.class));   //false
```